# What topology is associated with locally uniform convergence?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

In other words, fill in the blank:

*$f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly if and only if for any open set $U$ w/r/t the ______ topology such that $f\in U$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $f_n\in U$.*

Comment: So as the answer below shows: we need "uniform-metric" topology here.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct your title, the statement is about uniform convergence. The topology in which convergence is given by the uniform convergence of functions is the topology inherited from the infinity norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ on $B(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of bounded functions), where $\Vert f \Vert_\infty = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \vert f(x) \vert.$ $B(\mathbb{R})$ becomes a Banach space with respect to this norm and it is easy to see that the notion of convergence on this space coincides with the usual notion of uniform convergence. I hope this helps. :)